# What is clipping the Label text?

Tags: xaml, maui

What is clipping the top left of my label in this image?

[image: P is clipped]

Here is the code I am using.

```xml
<!--Column 1-->
<Border
    Grid.Column="0"
    WidthRequest="40" 
    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20,20,20,20"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"
    Padding="6,6"
    Margin="10"
    HeightRequest="40">
    <Label FontSize="28"
        FontFamily="serif" 
        Text="{Binding DocCode}"
        TextColor="#FFFFFFDE"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: What version of MAUI are you using? On which platform? I tried your code and I can't see the clipping.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. What if you take down the `RoundRectangle` to 18 or just set padding to 0? What have you tried so far.

Comment: Difficult to say, it could be related to the Padding, the FontSize and/or a bug in the Border control. But it would be useful to know more about the .NET version you're using and which platform this occurs on.

Comment: Using .Net 7 for the Window platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is .NET 7 and this is a known bug in iOS which was fixed in .NET 8, more information can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17753

If you cannot move to .NET 8 just use `Frame` until you can move

Comment: It is running in the Windows environment.  For whatever reason, I tried switching to Android to test and it runs but does not run to where it will accept input?  Not sure what that is about.  But the screen shot is Windows no iOS.  I will upgrade to .Net 8.

Comment: Looks like it works fine in .Net 8.  Also, the problem was under Windows not iOS, but upgrading fixed it for me.